# How can I see my IOPS burst credits?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been reading some [EBS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html)

and they are talking about "I/O credit balance" 
How can I view my current (or historical) credit balance?

> Each volume receives an initial I/O credit balance of 5,400,000 I/O
>   credits, which is enough to sustain the maximum burst performance of
>   3,000 IOPS for 30 minutes. This initial credit balance is designed to
>   provide a fast initial boot cycle for boot volumes and to provide a
>   good bootstrapping experience for other applications. Volumes earn I/O
>   credits every second at a base performance rate of 3 IOPS per GiB of
>   volume size. For example, a 100 GiB General Purpose (SSD) volume has a
>   base performance of 300 IOPS.

Comment: Simple answer is you can't. But this link might be useful future readers: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=164462

Comment: You can a tleast know that you are running out of credits by looking at the queue depth stat. Queue depth is ["the number of I/O requests in the queue waiting to be serviced."](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#Concepts.Storage)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

AWS recently added Burst Balance metric to monitor your balance, the metrics is 0-100% and says how far is your volume from 5.4 million.

[The AWS Blog post about it](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-burst-balance-metric-for-ec2s-general-purpose-ssd-gp2-volumes/?platform=hootsuite)

This is available for EC2 gp2 Volumes as well as RDS gp2 Volumes.

To view it for EC2 EBS Volumes, go to Cloudwatch -> Metrics -> EBS -> BurstBalance.

To view it for RDS Instances, go to Cloudwatch -> Metrics -> RDS -> BurstBalance.

Comment: Where can I find it? I don't see such metric in Browser Metrics list

Comment: Ok, I just realised I need it for RDS. It's available only for EC2

Comment: Nice tip. This should be available from RDS monitor console too.

Comment: the correct metric is `EBSIOBalance%`

Answer (score 2):

**You can't**. As in the [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=164462) provided by AgDude:

From Nov 5, 2014:

> Unfortunately there isn't a Cloudwatch Metric for the current IOPS
>   Credit balance like there is with the CPU credits but I am definitely
>   submitting a feature request through to our EBS/Cloudwatch teams for
>   such a metric.

Up to now, Nov 2, 2015, this feature was not implemented yet.

Comment: This answer was correct as of writing, but is now replaced by @Darek 's answer below